# Como utilizar tensorflow de un contenedor docker en un contenedor con django? Enlazar Contenedores?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, tensorflow

Necesito enlazar dos contenedores, mi contenedor principal contiene django y el secundario tensorflow, estoy creando los dos contenedores con docker-compose, los dos se crean correctamente, pero necesito entrar al contenedor con django y al correr python poder hacer un import tensorflow as tf dentro del contenedor con django, ya que el proyecto que voy a correr en el contenedor de django utilizar tensorflow, pero he tenido problemas para crear un contenedor que tenga django y tensorflow, por esa razón estoy creando dos contenedores pero necesito enlazarlos para poder usar tensorflow en el proyecto con django.

Este es mi Dockerfile base de python3

```
 FROM python:3
 MAINTAINER Eduardo Barrios
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/     
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

Mi archivo de requirements.txt

```
 Django==2.1
 psycopg2
 numpy
 opencv-python
 opencv-contrib-python
```

Y el docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'

 services:
   web:  
     image: ebarrioscode/django_python
     container_name: django_python
     build: .
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     ports:
       - "8081:8081"   
     depends_on:
       - tensorflow
     links:
       - tensorflow
       - tensorflow:8888

   tensorflow:
     image: tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0-gpu
     container_name: tensorflow_python
     ports:
       - 8888:8888
```

## Actualización

He cambiado mi dockerfile y docker-compose ahora solo utilizo un contenedor el cuál contiene tensorflow e instalo mendiante pip o RUN pip install django en el Dockerfile, la manera para iniciar el proyecto django dentro del container es accediendo al contenedor y desde adentro hacer un python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081.

Estoy exponiendo el puerto 8081 en el Dockerfile para que por este puerto salga mi aplicación django, también se expone este puerto en el docker-compose.yml

Así quedo mi Dockerfile

```
 FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
 MAINTAINER Eduardo Barrios

 COPY ./keyboard /etc/default/keyboard
 RUN apt-get update 

 RUN pip install --upgrade python
 RUN apt-get --yes --force-yes install python-pip
 RUN pip install numpy
 RUN pip install scipy
 RUN pip install plotly
 RUN pip install tflearn
 RUN apt-get install python-opencv -y
 RUN apt-get update
 RUN pip install 
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp27- 
none-linux_x86_64.whl
 RUN python -m pip install jupyter
 RUN pip install django

 ENV CUDA_VERSION 8.0.61

 ENV CUDA_PKG_VERSION 8-0=$CUDA_VERSION-1
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-nvrtc-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-nvgraph-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cusolver-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cublas-8-0=8.0.61.2-1 \
    cuda-cufft-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-curand-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cusparse-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-npp-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cudart-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION && \
ln -s cuda-8.0 /usr/local/cuda && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


 LABEL com.nvidia.volumes.needed="nvidia_driver"
 LABEL com.nvidia.cuda.version="${CUDA_VERSION}"

 RUN echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf && \
     echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf

 ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
 ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

 EXPOSE 6006
 EXPOSE 8081 
 EXPOSE 8886 
 EXPOSE 8888

 CMD jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root
```

Así quedo el archivo docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'

 services:
   djangotf:
     image: ebarrioscode/tensorflow
     container_name: ia_project
     build: .
     volumes:
       - ./files:/notebooks
     ports:
       - "8081:8081"
       - "8888:8888"
```

El proyecto ya funciona tuve algunos problemas con el puerto 8081 pero se resuelve borrando la imagen generada anteriormente ya que está se almacena en caché y hace que la etapa del build sea más rápida, pero esto me generaba errores al exponer el puerto 8081.

Comment: Hola @abulafia gracias por tu respuesta, voy a intentar la primera opción que me das, la segunda parece ser compleja, te comento que he intentado crear un contenedor con base en python:3 y django y luego he tratado de instalar mediante pip tensorflow pero he tenido muchos errores

Comment: Creo que deberías editar la pregunta y añadir un apartado "Actualización" en el que expliques qué has hecho a raíz de estos comentarios, cómo es actualmente tu Dockerfile y tu docker-compose y qué problema te estás encontrando ahora. Después puedes borrar todos estos comentarios para "limpiar".

Comment: Lo que dice @abulafia es una buena idea, deberías mover los comentarios a la pregunta y añadir los datos adicionales. Los comentarios no son para mantener conversaciones extendidas, porque no se indexan y podrían borrarse en cualquier momento.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios muchachos, he agregado la actualización y el cambio en los archivos que generaban el problema, también borrado los comentarios.

Comment: @EduardoBarrios Entonces ¿ya funciona todo? ¿Pregunta resuelta?

Comment: @abulafia claro ya funciona todo, gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Aunque esto es más bien un comentario, es demasiado largo para ponerlo como tal y por tanto lo escribo en una respuesta.

El fichero `Dockerfile` que muestras en la actualización no es muy eficiente, porque contiene muchos comandos RUN. Cada comando RUN da lugar a una nueva capa en la imagen final. El número total de capas es limitado por lo que en general es buena idea minimizar el número de ellas, y es por eso que suelen verse muchos comandos separados por `&&` en un solo RUN.

En el caso de instalar paquetes python, la técnica habitual es escribir un archivo llamado `requirements.txt` que contenga los nombres de los paquetes a instalar (uno por línea), y si mejor aún si especifica las versiones concretas de cada paquete (si ya lo tenías todo instalado localmente en un entorno virtual, el comando `pip freeze` puede servirte para obtener la lista de paquetes instalados y sus versiones, y de este modo te aseguras de que la imagen del contenedor será 100% compatible con la que tu usaste aunque sea creada en otro momento en que hayan salido versiones nuevas).

El `RUN apt-get update` que has añadido se repite más adelante. Yo juntaría todos los `apt` en un solo RUN, poniéndolos delante de los `pip install`.

Por último, si no quieres tener que entrar en el contenedor a lanzar "a mano" el servidor django, podrías crear (fuera del contenedor) un archivo `lanzar-todo.sh` que contenga las dos líneas siguientes:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081
```

y copiar ese archivo al contenedor para lanzarlo en el `CMD` final.
En definitiva, el Dockerfile quedaría así:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
MAINTAINER Eduardo Barrios

COPY ./keyboard /etc/default/keyboard
COPY ./requirements.txt /
COPY ./lanzar-todo.sh /

# Instalar primero cuda
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-nvrtc-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-nvgraph-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cusolver-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cublas-8-0=8.0.61.2-1 \
    cuda-cufft-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-curand-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cusparse-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-npp-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-cudart-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION && \
    ln -s cuda-8.0 /usr/local/cuda && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV CUDA_VERSION 8.0.61
ENV CUDA_PKG_VERSION 8-0=$CUDA_VERSION-1

LABEL com.nvidia.volumes.needed="nvidia_driver"
LABEL com.nvidia.cuda.version="${CUDA_VERSION}"

RUN echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf && \
    echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf

ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

# Instalar después python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --force-yes \
    python-opencv python-pip  && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Instalar todos los paquetes python necesarios (django, etc)
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Exponer puertos
EXPOSE 6006
EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 8886
EXPOSE 8888

# Lanzar jupyter y django
CMD /lanzar-todo.sh
```

Por otro lado, ya que partes de una imagen base que ya trae instalado cuda, no sé hasta qué punto es necesario toda la parte que instala y configura cuda.

Comment: No había pensado en eso, tienes toda la razón lo voy a cambiar para que sea más eficiente, gracias @abulafia

Comment: Lo he cambiado pero me da un erro al llegar a # Instalar después python el error es E: Unable to locate package install
E: Unable to locate package python-opencv
E: Unable to locate package python-pip

Comment: @EduardoBarrios El `install` sobraba. No entiendo en cambio por qué no encuentra los otros paquetes. Acabo de modificar la respuesta para añadir un `apt-get update` antes, pero yo entiendo que no era necesario pues ya lo habíamos hecho en un RUN anterior...